# Rotating non-symmetrical symbols, or avoiding upside down symbols

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology

I have a lovely symbol of a vehicle on a map (as an SVG path). I'd like to show current heading.

Trouble is, cars aren't symmetrical. I am ending up with a lot of vehicles that look like this. Not what my bosses want to see.

[image]

My question: is there a way to flip this symbol or load a different symbol if the heading would make it be upside down? Or, more succinctly, **how to I keep the cars right side up**?

My code:

```
    tempRenderer = new UniqueValueRenderer(basicSymbol, "age");
    tempRenderer.addValue(0, new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_PATH, 20, '', new Color([0,0,0,1])).setPath(truckSVG));
    tempRenderer.setColorInfo({
        field: "temp",
        stops: [
            { value: -30, color: new Color([255, 255, 255]) },  
            { value: 0, color: new Color([200, 128, 200]) },    
            { value: 30, color: new Color([128, 128, 255]) },
            { value: 60, color: new Color([128, 255, 255]) }
        ]
    });
    tempRenderer.setSizeInfo({
        field: "age",
        stops: [
            { value: 0, size: 40 },  
            { value: 1, size: 10 },    
            { value: 30, size: 4 }
        ]
    });
    tempRenderer.setRotationInfo({
        field: "heading",
        type: "geographic"
    });
    truckLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    truckLayer.setRenderer(tempRenderer);
    map.addLayer(truckLayer);
```

As you can see, I'm showing the last 30 minutes of data for where the vehicle has been. The newest one gets a cool truck icon, while older ones get a dot. The temperature at the vehicle's location determines the color, the age of the data determines the size of the dot.

The data is being pulled in as a plain old json file (not an esri service). I suppose it'd be possible to put the latest point in a separate layer.

I can create an SVG facing the opposite direction if necessary and manipulate the headings and set a flag if needed.

Comment: i *think* the easiest solution would be to create two icons and ensure that your rendering rule differentiates the eastward and westward facing trucks using the value from 'heading' field.